# Log monitor problem with Java and org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer

Tags: java, file, logging, monitor

I am trying to use this to monitor a log file and put the log lines in a database as they come in. The problem I am having is that it seems while the thread containing my TailerListener is running, I cannot delete or rename the log file. This being the case, I am not sure how this will react when the log file rolls over, which happens nightly. I glanced at the code for Tailer and it appears to handle log rollover, but I can't see how when the file being monitored is basically locked.

There should be no reason the file cannot be deleted as I am only reading from it. I would think once the file was deleted/renamed it would simply throw some type of exception. Especially since Tailer seems to be written aiming at the functionality of "tail -f".

The exact error I am getting when trying to delete the file: "This action can't be completed because the file is open in Java(TM) Platform SE binary"

Here is the sample code from my project:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        File pcounter_log = new File("c:\development\temp\test.log");
```

```
    try {
        TailerListener listener = new PCTailListener();
        Tailer tailer = new Tailer(pcounter_log, listener, 5000);

        Thread thread = new Thread(tailer);
        thread.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

```
public class PCTailListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {
 public void handle(String line) {
  System.out.println(line);
 }
}
```

Any information on this regarding Tailer specificially, file handling in Java, anything that might put me on the right track is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If a process is using that file, you can't delete/rename it, but you can read it. What you could do is to copy the file and perform all operations in the copied file.

Why you can't modify it? Because maybe there's an opened stream locking the file.

Comment: Yes I understand that. My confusion comes from the fact that this library was built with this in mind if you look at the interface methods: http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/TailerListenerAdapter.html

Comment: You're right, the interface describes exception handling when the file changes or 'rotates'. Perhaps some other process/thread is dealing with the file?

Comment: But checking at the code, the Tailer class holds a reference to the file, it's only handling the exceptions. There's no part where it says that the files does not stay locked.

Comment: I see what is happening. The way the file rotation is supposed to work is that the target file is not renamed and a new one created in its place. Rather, the file is "rotated" when all the data is deleted and its length is less than the current position in the file. Now I just need to make sure the application I am monitoring rotates log files correctly or naively.